# Move files up one level when folders have spaces

Tags: batch-file

I use a batch file to move files up one level and generally it works, but it fails with folders have spaces. How can I make this script work with folders that have spaces?

```
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims==" %%f in ('dir %%i /a:d /b') do (move "%%i\%%f\*" "%%i"&&rd "%%i\%%f" /s /q)
```

Comment: `dir %%i /a:d /b` --> `dir "%%i" /a:d /b`...

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. That was very quick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unquoted path at the `dir` command parsed by the inner `for /F` loop. You need to change `dir %%i /a:d /b` to `dir "%%i" /a:d /b`, like this:

```cmd
for /f "delims= eol=|" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims= eol=|" %%f in ('dir "%%i" /a:d /b') do (move "%%i\%%f\*" "%%i"&&rd "%%i\%%f" /s /q)
```

I also changed the `for /F` option `delims==` (`=` is the delimiter, which might occur) to `delims=` (no delimiter) and added `eol=|` (`eol` defaults to `;` which might occur in paths, but `|` cannot).